# Animation loops even if Loop Time is unchecked in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, slider

Hi I have a question about why animations keep looping even though I have the animation loop time unchecked and using boolean to control what happens.  Below is my code to make my robot die as well as screen shots of Mechanim.

ZoltainHealth.cs

```
void Update () {
    if (!isAlive(ZoltainHealthSlider.value)) {
        isDead = true;
        gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Die");

        if (isDead) {
            isDead = false;
            gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Alive");
            reset(gameObject, startingPos, gameObject.tag);
            gameObject.GetComponent<Slider>().value = 100f;
        }
    }
}
```

Base Class Characters.cs where I get is Alive()

```
public bool isAlive(float life) {
    bool isAlive = true;

    int health = Mathf.RoundToInt(life);

    if (health <= 0) {
        isAlive = false;
    }
    return isAlive;
}
```

Screenshot of Mechanim: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0aki.png)

I'm also having problems with the health slider resetting back to full amount when Zoltan is regenerated after having been dead to start a new game as written in the if (isDead) code below.

Comment: Is `ZoltainHealthSlider` the same as `gameObject.GetComponent<Slider>()`?

Comment: yeah they are the same thing, but I don't think it should make that much of a difference as this script is attached to Zoltan.  void Start () {
        currentHealth = base.totalHealth;
        ZoltainHealthSlider = GetComponentInChildren<Slider>();
        startingPos = gameObject.transform.position;
        isDead = false;
  
 }

Comment: When I click on the trigger buttons for the parameters Die and Alive in mechanim separately the animation works fine in the preview.  For some reason or another it is not doing the same when I call SetTrigger("Die") and SetTrigger("Alive") from code.  To test this I was pausing the game and manually changing the Zoltan Health Bar slider to zero to see if he does his dying animation happens or not.  I think its probably better to create a test script instead to test whether or not he dies.

Comment: So if the Health slide to 0, you want to trigger `"Die"` and `"Alive"` simultaneously? And what animation transition with these two triggers? The screenshot doesn't contain those info.

Comment: When the slider goes to zero,  die animation should play.  When the slider goes to 100, then the Zolo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to play the `Die` animation then Play the `Alive` animation and reset the status.

Then the below code should do the job.

```
void Update () {
    if (!isAlive(ZoltainHealthSlider.value)) {
        StartCoroutine (WaitDieAnimationFinishAndPlayAlive);
    }
}

private void WaitDieAnimationFinishAndPlayAlive () {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(DieAnimationTime);
    gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Alive");
    StartCoroutine (WaitAliveAnimationFinishAndReset);
}
private void WaitAliveAnimationFinishAndReset () {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(AliveAnimationTime);
    reset(gameObject, startingPos, gameObject.tag);
    gameObject.GetComponent<Slider>().value = 100f;
}
```

I am not sure the animation looping problem you encountered whether is caused by setting the `Die` and `Alive` triggers at the same `Update` frame.

Comment: Hey Ming, sorry for the late feedback, thanks for your help.  I eventually solved the problem which was similar to the  that you have provided.if (isAlive(ZoltainHealthSlider.value) == false)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Death());

            if (gameOverCanvas.activeSelf == false)
                gameOverCanvas.SetActive(true);

        }